# getting data to array in knockout JS

Tags: codeigniter, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to get data to knockout from the database using Ajax. But I am not getting any data to my `observableArray.`

Here is the knockout js model:

```
self.alldata = ko.observableArray();

self.viewAllInvoice = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/learn_Ko/',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    })
    .done(function(invoices) {
    invoices.forEach(function(invoice) {
      self.alldata.push(invoice);
    });
  })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
    })
    .always(function(data){       

    });
};
self.viewAllInvoice();
```

And here is the html code I am trying to put my data in

```html
<tbody data-bind="foreach: alldata">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.payment_amount "></span></td>
    <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.allocated_amount"></span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I did not create a viewmodel showing all the data from the database since I know what I need to show in the table. And for extra information, I am getting the data from a controller in codeigniter framework. Please do guide me in steps since I am totally new in all this.

Comment: The code you've posted will work just fine. Please make sure you include a full repro for the problem. Check "[mcve]" for guidance.

Comment: Sorry for not adding more information, but thanks for helping as much as you could, I still couldnt get it working, but will try harder to see whats wrong, thanks alot!

Comment: Good luck! Get back to us if you have a minimal repro.

Comment: Have you debugged to see if you get the invoices in the `.done` and how they look like? Why are you pushing the invoices one by one instead of doing `self.alldata(invoices)` to load them all in a single step? Have you opened the browser's console and seen any error mesage? Is your invocation of ajax call reaching your server?

Comment: @JotaBe Yea the ajax call is reaching my server, I was just trying different ways to see if it works or not, since self.alldata(invoices) did not work, so I just tried different ways.

Comment: if `self.alldata(invoces)` is not working, it's because it is not an array or because you have an error somewhere else.Have you checked what `invoices` contained in your browser debugger? have you look fr other possible errors in your browser console?